# Proof that theorems about trace of matrix :

Tags: matrices, trace

Can somebody help me about proofs of this theorems

A is an nxn matrix and $\ A^2$ = mA then,
tr(A) = m rank(A) .

A is an nxn matrix and k is a positive integer then,
tr($\ A^k$) =  $\sum_{i=1}^n λ_i^k$  where λ's are the characteristic roots of A.

Thanks for helping...

Comment: Do you know Jordan form of a Matrix? There lie all your answers

Comment: Can you explain proofs ? this is important for me my homework.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A^2=mA$ then the polynomial $P=x(x-m)$ annihilates $A$ and then

$$\operatorname{sp}(A)\subset \{0,m\}$$

- if $m=0$ then the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$ hence $A$ is nilpotent and the equality $\operatorname{tr} A=m\operatorname{rank}A$ is trivial.
- if $m\ne0$ then if $\operatorname{sp}(A)= \{m\}$ then $A=mI_n$ so $\operatorname{tr} A=nm=m\operatorname{rank}A$ and if $\operatorname{sp}(A)= \{0\}$ then $A$ is nilpotent with index say $p$ so we have

$$0=A^p=mA^{p-1}\implies A=0$$
and the equality is trivial. Finally if $\operatorname{sp}(A)= \{0,m\}$ then the rank of $A$ is the multiplicity of $m$ and the equality is also clear.

For the second result: we know that every matrix is triangularizable over $\Bbb C$
so there's an invertible matrix $P$ such that

$$A=P\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&\times&\cdots&\times
\\&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
&\Large0&\ddots&\times\\
&&&\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}$$
hence
$$A^k=P\begin{pmatrix}\lambda^k_1&\times&\cdots&\times
\\&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
&\Large0&\ddots&\times\\
&&&\lambda^k_n\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}$$
and the result follows easily.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the trace of a matrix is invariant by similarity. That means you can transform every matrix in his [Jordan form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), where the trace is the sum of all eigenvalues, with their algebraic multiplicity.

Now, if $A^2=mA$, it means that his minimal polynomial divides $x^2-mx=x(x-m)$, so $A$ has only $0$ and $m$ as eigenvalues, and $A$ is diagonalizable.
Thus, the algebraic (and geometric) multiplicity of the null eigenvelue is the dimension of his Ker, and the multiplicity of $m$ is the rank, so $Tr(A)=m*rk(A)$.

If $A=MJM^{-1}$, with $J$ in Jordan form, then $A^k=MJ^kM^{-1}$. Since $J$ is triangular, $J^k$ has on the main diagonal the $k$-th powers of the diagonal elements of $J$, meaning that  $tr(A^k)=\sum_{i=1}^n λ_i^k$